# Can you help me with bug in array or enum in Unity3d project?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, enums

Hi I am begginning to develop game in Unity3d and I have bug in my code or in inspector.

My bug is in the array arthursButtonsDescription where I am assigning itemToEquip twice. First turn everything goes well arthursButtonsDescription[0].name is "0", but second turn i assign arthursButtonsDescription[4].name=4 and arthursButtonsDescription[0].name is 4 too and here is my bug.

I recorded video about this bug: https://youtu.be/wZuFo5uhL5o

And I uploaded my bugged project to: https://uloz.to/file/zfyxYuOiHTa4/dandd-zip#!ZGp4LmR2AzV0MTSvMGxkMwOvZwEuBGEuIRuhIyM6MJAgFGIuAj==/dandd-zip

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite icon = null;
    public bool showInInventory = true;
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Equipment : Item
{
    public EquipmentSlot equipSlot;

    new public string name = "New Item";
}

public enum EquipmentSlot { Head, Chest, Legs, Foot, Shield, Weapon, 
    Potion20Hp, Potion40Hp, Potion60Hp, Potion80Hp, Potion100Hp, 
    Potion25Percent, Potion50Percent, Potion75Percent, Potion100Percent }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoadStarter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadClick()
    {
        Equipment itemToEquip = gameObject.AddComponent<Equipment>();

        itemToEquip.name = "0";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Head;
        Debug.Log("iTE0: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);

        itemToEquip.name = "4";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Shield;
        Debug.Log("iTE4: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EquipmentManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static EquipmentManager instance;
    public void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("EquipmentManager instance not equals null");
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
    }

    public ArthurInventory ai;

    public void Equip(Equipment newItem)
    {
        ai = FindObjectOfType(typeof(ArthurInventory)) as ArthurInventory;
        ai.ShowArthursButtons(newItem);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ArthurInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] arthursButtons/* = new GameObject[6]*/;
    public Equipment[] arthursButtonsDescription = new Equipment[6];
    public void ShowArthursButtons(Equipment newItem)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arthursButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arthursButtons[i].name == "HellmButton" && newItem.equipSlot == EquipmentSlot.Head)
            {
                arthursButtons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Image>().enabled = true;
                arthursButtonsDescription[0] = newItem;
            }
            if (arthursButtons[i].name == "ShieldButton" && newItem.equipSlot == EquipmentSlot.Shield)
            {
                arthursButtons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Image>().enabled = true;
                arthursButtonsDescription[4] = newItem;
                Debug.Log("AI0: " + arthursButtonsDescription[0].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the same object reference to multiple places in your array -> you actually are changing the value of the same object ... Does your `Item` class have to be a `MonoBehaviour` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in SaveLoadStarter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoadStarter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadClick()
    {
        Equipment itemToEquip = gameObject.AddComponent<Equipment>();

        itemToEquip.name = "0";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Head;
        Debug.Log("iTE0: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);

        itemToEquip.name = "4";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Shield;
        Debug.Log("iTE4: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);
    }
}
```

You declare itemToEquip, set it, then set it again.

You need to create a new Equipment object.  Otherwise you are just changing the values in the first object.

Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoadStarter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadClick()
    {
        Equipment itemToEquip = gameObject.AddComponent<Equipment>();

        itemToEquip.name = "0";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Head;
        Debug.Log("iTE0: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);

        itemToEquip = gameObject.AddComponent<Equipment>();

        itemToEquip.name = "4";
        itemToEquip.equipSlot = EquipmentSlot.Shield;
        Debug.Log("iTE4: " + itemToEquip.name);
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(itemToEquip);
    }
}
```

Comment: This way you would end up with multiple `Equipment` components on the same gameObject though which might most of the time break stuff ... Question is though @OP: does your `Item` class even need to be a `MonoBehaviour` at all?

Comment: Thanks alot man. This works. I hope that sometime I will be such skilled programmer something like you. I think that my Item class doesnt need to be MonoBehaviour. Will this repair my bug?

Comment: `itemToEquip = new Equipment();` will solve this error better? Or i should destroy itemToEquip?

Comment: @Mr.Koala I don't know.  According to the documentation AddComponent "Adds a component class of type componentType to the game object." so I guess it depends on if you need the equipment in the game object.  I would not destroy itemToEquip since you added it to the game object, unless you don't need it there anymore.

Comment: @Trisped if it is not a `MonoBehaviour` then yes `new Equipment` would be allowed and solve it the same way .... the essential point is: You had the same reference to the same object in two different places in the collection ... creating a new instance everytime solves thi